# What is the bias from choosing best train/test set from many options called?

Tags: machine-learning

I am confident that the below methodology creates a bias in that it indirectly uses the test set as part of the training procedure, however, I am having trouble explaining this to my colleagues. I would greatly appreciate any relevant terminology or reading material to help me articulate the problem.

Here is an example scenario:

- I have a dataset split into three chunks A, B, and C.
- I use two chunks to train my model, and one to test.
- I try all permutations of test/train splits (ie using each AB, AC, BC
  as training), and get different results each time.
- I report the performance from the best of the splits as the performance of my model on this data.

In reality, this value is an over-optimistic evaluation of my model's performance because I have essentially looked at all the data and chosen the best way to split it. This is cheating because I have looked at my test data before evaluating. The actual performance of my model would be the average performance of all split permutations.

What is the bias I have introduced called?

What is this (common) mistake called?

Where/how can I find a more complete description of this problem?

Comment: As you said, you should report the mean over *all* train/test splits, in which case you basically end up with a form of (stratified) cross-validation. If the performance varies a lot, I would even report individual measures. The approach you describe is a form of cherry picking, and is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate your forecast accuracy, what you want to do is [cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)). What you *don't* want to do is [data dredging, data fishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging).